# Why does ConvertAPI gives me error in drupal7

Tags: api, drupal-7, converters, convertapi

I m using **[ConvertAPI](https://www.convertapi.com/docx-to-jpg)** for convert doc to jpg . It works  correct in PHP. But When I put same code In drupal 7 it Gives me error below

**ConvertApi\Error\Api: File link is set incorrectly. URL or File Id must be set.**

**My code is :**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \ConvertApi\ConvertApi;

ConvertApi::setApiSecret('your-api-secret');

$result = ConvertApi::convert('jpg', ['File' => 'uploads/Wheels1231231a1_1.docx']);
```

## save to file

```
$result->getFile()->save('uploads/file1.jpg');
```

Comment: Pass full path to File , something like => `'File' => drupal_realpath('public://uploads/Wheels1231231a1_1.docx'))`

Comment: @Fky . Its work perfect. Thanks.
Now I have one issue  I want  to store files in **Amazon S3** which converted using this API .So,can u please tell me how I store Files in **Amazon S3**

Comment: Create Another post to explain exactly you need with Amazon S3

Comment: ok thanks for help @Fky

Comment: How to convert all pages which is in docx to jpg using above code ?
Suppose in docs have 3 pages then convert all 3 pages as a jpg file with different files

Comment: @PatelNitesh to save all converted files to JPG you need to execute this code `$savedFiles = $result->saveFiles($dir);`

Comment: @Tomas . thanks for help